# Jersey : HttpServletRequest is coming as Proxy while using @context

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I have a jersey rest controller called Test.

```
@Path("/listusers")
public class Test {
    @Context 
    private HttpServletRequest request;
        @GET
    public void listUser(){
        System.out.println("testing...");
            //getting parameters from the request and doing something
    }
}
```

When I run the code, I am getting error saying that

> No thread local value in scope for proxy of class
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18

I am not able to understand the reason for this. I have some other classes where I am using similar url, without any problem.

I tried googling, but was not able to find any solution.

My web.xml entry is

```
<servlet>
      <servlet-name>rest-controller</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
      <init-param>
       <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
       <param-value>com.mypackage</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>rest-controller</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/listusers</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Which Jersey version, web container are you using? How are you invoking the resource method?

Comment: @MichalGajdos I am using **bold**jersey 1.8**bold** and eclipse. Sample code as below:   `WebResource resource =  resource = authClient.resource(url);ClientResponse clientResponse = null;Client authClient = Client.create();clientResponse = resource.queryParams(queryParam).post(ClientResponse.class);
        response = clientResponse.getEntity(String.class);`

Comment: Also, in one place I am trying to forward to another jersey controller in the same was u forward to another servlet. I doubt if that is the reason.